# Short Story: Humans battle against hyper-intelligent dogs for dominance

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, animals

Am looking for the title of a short story I read in one of the popular science fiction periodicals.  It was published sometime between 1995-2005, mostly likely in 1996-1999.

In the near future dogs were manipulated to give them intelligence equal to or greater than man.  That starts them fighting humans to be the dominant species on earth.

The story follows a kind of soldier/bounty hunter as he goes about his job of trying to kill dogs.  He is paid higher bounties for the most dangerous ones, e.g., the alpha male is the most valuable.

The setting seems to be that large previously inhabited areas have been abandoned to the dog packs and humans have fortified themselves within other urban areas.  Most humans feel like the battle is a stalemate, but scientists have predicted the dogs will inevitably wear down humanity's defenses.

A significant portion of the story takes place in a parking structure.

Comment: Well, unless you've elaborated considerably in memory it's probably not INTO YOUR TENT I'LL CREEP by Eric Frank Russell, but I'd just like to park it as a suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: Thanks for the idea Simon, but that's definitely not it.  The setting here is when the balance of power is essentially even.

Comment: Sounds a lot like Howard Myers' story Fit for a Dog.  Similarities: intelligent dogs, abandoned countryside, people whose job is to kill dogs.  Differences: characters are more like security guards than soldiers, no bounties, sense of inferiority is expressed by the guards rather than scientists or the populace.

Comment: Hi Leif, thanks for the idea.  This story definitely included bounties.  Also I think the story was written in the late 90s, as there was no indication that the periodical was republishing this story.